# trailing stop loss in slow price decline

Tags: limit-order

If I set the trailing stop loss as 5% based on Last. Is the stop price updated every time Last is published? e.g. If the current Last is $100, then current stop price is $95; when the next Last comes, say $101, and then the next stop price is $95.95 (101 * .95). Is this correct?

For a sell order, if the most recent Last is below .95 of the previous Last, order executes. What if the latest Last falls just 2% of previous Last and the stock keeps falling and Last declines 2% per Last, would the order execute?

Comment: A trailing stop loss is usually based on the latest high price traded not the last price traded.   A trailing stop can move up but can never move down.

Answer (score 3):

The price doesn't have to drop 5% *in one go* to activate your order. The trailing aspect simply means your sell trigger price will increase if the current value increases (it will never decrease).

### Example 1: start with a valuation of $100 and a trailing 5% loss trigger

- Price increases to $105 (+5%). Trigger price is increased to $99.75.
- Price drops to $104 (-1%). Trigger price remains at $99.75.
- Price drops to $102 (-2%). Trigger price remains at $99.75.
- Price drops to $100 (-2%). Trigger price remains at $99.75.
- Price drops to $98 (-2%). Market order executes.

### Example 2: start with a valuation of $100 and a trailing 5% loss trigger

- Price drops to $98 (-2%). Trigger price remains at $95.
- Price drops to $96 (-2%). Trigger price remains at $95.
- Price increases to $102 (+6%). Trigger price is increased to $96.90.
- Price drops to $96 (-6%). Market order executes.